# Why cant the compiler differenciate between a static and a normal member function with the same name/parameters

Tags: c++

Now I know why it wouldnt work if the difference was the return type, but I really dont get why the below functions would be ambiguos:

```
template<typename... Args>
static void addTo(const Entity &en, Args...args){
//something
}
and
    template<typename... Args>
void addTo(const Entity &en, Args...args)
```

Now please do explain the way this works in the background, since I dont seem to know enough about how this stuff works. In my mind it should work since:

Both functions are called differently (different operators, one runs off the classname itself and one off an instance)

~~My Guess~~

Now this is just a guess but it seems to be the only logical explanation, so bear with me.
So as far as I know every member function is expanded to the fully qualified name (i hope thats what its called). So both functions are expanded to Class::addTo, which leads to the compiler not being able to tell them apart.

~~What Gives?~~

I really have no idea why this shouldnt work. Both on the design aspect (why shouldnt this work) and on a technical aspect (except my guess above).

Comment: Can you give us some context please? Preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You can call a static member on an object instance too. I imagine that's the bit you weren't aware of.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was aware of it but I didnt think of that. Makes a whole lot more sense now. Also that other post that I accepted as solving my issue did help too.